# Cropper.js canvas iphone image rotation

Tags: ios, image, canvas, crop

I am using cropper.js to crop an image. But it looks like when I am cropping the image in an iphone/ipad sometimes (not always) the canvas is rotated but only for portrait images.  I searched and found out that it's a canvas issue with iOS. Is there any way that I could make it work ? I tried to used the exif metadata from the image and get the orientation but then I found that the not all the images have the exif metadata (some people can remove them and png images don't have those metadata at all). Any suggestions on how I could fix this rotation problem?

Comment: Have you solved your issue? please share